# Using mod_rewrite to update urls after ViewVC migration

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2.2

At work we have a ViewVC system which has been migrated from one machine to another. The version has also been upgraded. The old system used `/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi` as the base of all its urls and the new system uses `/viewvc`. The hostname remains the same.

We have a lot of documentation which has ViewVC links and I would like those to still work as before. I'm a software developer by day so not an expert on apache but I thought that `mod_rewrite` would be the right route. Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to do what I want.

Without any changes, when I go to the url `/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi` I get a 404. Here's what I see in the apache logs:

```
==> /var/log/httpd/error_log <==
[Thu May 31 03:13:10 2012] [error] [client 172.16.3.52] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi

==> /var/log/httpd/access_log <==
172.16.3.52 - - [31/May/2012:03:13:10 +0100] "GET /cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 289 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.17 Safari/536.11"
```

When I add the `RewriteEngine`/`RewriteRule` entries to `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` as below ...

```
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi(.*) /viewvc$1
</Directory>
```

I get a 403. Here's what's in the logs:

```
==> /var/log/httpd/error_log <==
[Thu May 31 03:15:35 2012] [error] [client 172.16.3.52] Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /var/www/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi

==> /var/log/httpd/access_log <==
172.16.3.52 - - [31/May/2012:03:15:35 +0100] "GET /cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi HTTP/1.1" 403 293 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.17 Safari/536.11"
```

If I edit the Options line above to include `FollowSymLinks` and `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` I'm back to a 404.

```
==> /var/log/httpd/error_log <==
[Thu May 31 03:17:20 2012] [error] [client 172.16.3.52] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi

==> /var/log/httpd/access_log <==
172.16.3.52 - - [31/May/2012:03:17:20 +0100] "GET /cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 289 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.17 Safari/536.11"
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have the rule wrong or have it put it in the wrong place? Is `mod_rewrite` even he correct approach?

**Versions**: In case it is important, I am on a Fedora 17 machine with the following packages:

- httpd-2.2.22-4.fc17.x86_64
- viewvc-1.1.13-2.fc17.noarch
- viewvc-httpd-wsgi-1.1.13-2.fc17.noarch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the problem was that 1) the period in the pattern match needed escaping and 2) I put the rule in the wrong place. I should have put it at the top level rather than under cgi-bin.

---

For completion, here's how I worked it out:

I turned on rewrite logging so I could see exactly what the rewrite engine was doing:

```
RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

Using the original rewrite rule, I get this being logged:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2012:23:43:49 +0100] [localhost/sid#b76f4018][rid#b6d4a058/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2012:23:43:49 +0100] [localhost/sid#b76f4018][rid#b6d4a058/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi(.*)' to uri '/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi'
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2012:23:43:49 +0100] [localhost/sid#b76f4018][rid#b6d4a058/initial] (1) pass through /cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi
```

When I changed the rule to escape the period:

```
RewriteRule ^/cgi-bin/viewvc\.cgi(.*) /viewvc$1
```

I got this logged.

```
192.168.1.64 - - [03/Jun/2012:00:08:53 +0100] [192.168.1.128/sid#b76ed018][rid#b6d39058/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/
192.168.1.64 - - [03/Jun/2012:00:08:53 +0100] [192.168.1.128/sid#b76ed018][rid#b6d39058/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/cgi-bin/viewvc\.cgi(.*)' to uri '/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/'
192.168.1.64 - - [03/Jun/2012:00:08:53 +0100] [192.168.1.128/sid#b76ed018][rid#b6d39058/initial] (2) rewrite '/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/' -> '/viewvc/'
```

So it was the bare "." that was making it not match. But this is "Any single character" according to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), so it was unclear to me why it didn't work.

The [rewriting guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) escapes them all over the place, but with no indication that it is required or why, which is a shame.